# No postgresql user created after new Windows install

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to use postgresql with Rails so I can run locally before deploying to Heroku.  I installed the latest version of postgresql (9.2.4) from enterprisedb.com.

When I try to double click the database in pgAdmin III, it asks for a postgresql password.  There is no Windows postgresql account in the user settings.  I did notice that during my subsequent uninstallation of the application, the uninstaller referenced a service user account "NetworkService."

If I try to run the command line psql command, it asks for a password, then it complains that authentication failed for (my windows login account name).  I tried entering my usual Windows account password, and that didn't work.

What's going wrong here?  I've read many posts of people running into password/account issues with this database.

Comment: Did you check/follow the EnterpriseDB installation docs? Was there a step that might have been overlooked? You can modify the pg_hba.conf file to be "trust" for local connections until you figure out why you don't have the password. Actually, if you supply the full "psql -d <yourdb> -U <the db user>" command that might help diagnose the problem too.

Comment: @bma are there (Windows) installation docs?  There's no obvious up-to-date document as far as I can tell.  Why the vote to close?

Comment: I didn't vote to close your question. As far as the docs are concerned, I see a docs section at the following link: http://www.enterprisedb.com/documentation/english. I have never used EDB so maybe the installation steps are incomplete, I don't know.

Comment: @bma Sorry I realized I should have posted the comment asking about the vote to close as a new line since it likely wasn't you.  Anyhow, the only installation documents I could find on the page you sent refer to the cloud-based service install, not the standard postgresql installation. I tried editing the pga_hba conf file as you suggested, but that made no difference.  I tried running psql -U postgresql and got the error: FATAL role "postgresql" does not exist.

Comment: "postgres" is generally the username, not "postgresql". Also, did you restart postgresql (or at least reload the config files)? The changes to pg_hba.conf won't take effect until that reload/restart happens.

Comment: @bma Ah that was the problem; `postgres` worked!  If you'd like, write an answer with the details (editing the configuration and using the correct username) and I'll accept.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> There is no Windows postgresql account in the user settings.

The installer for 9.2 doesn't create a `postgres` Windows  user account. People were having too many problems with the service account password, getting confused between the service account and the `postgres` database account, etc. It now installs and runs as `NETWORKSERVICE` by default.

You will have set a PostgreSQL database password when you installed. You must log in to PostgreSQL as the `postgres` user with the password you gave during installation.

Answer (score 3):

With the help of [bma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2521566/bma), I was able to get my Rails application running on Windows by following these steps:

1. Install [postgresql](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#windows) for Windows.
2. Open the pgAdmin III application from the Windows Start Menu.
3. Click on the `File` menu, click `Open pg_hba.conf`
4. Browse to `C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.2\data\pg_hba.conf`.
5. Double click each of the rows and change `md5` to `trust`